# What happened to the "percent accepted" animation?

Tags: discussion, statistics

When did the site take down the animation that indicated what percentage of responses the OP had accepted, and what was the rationale for it?

I thought that was a useful tool to remind users to be a part of both the asking of questions and receiving of answers.

Comment: There was never an animation, only a visualization. That being said, it disappeared pretty much exactly a year ago, on January 22nd 2013, and not on a whim, but after at least seven months of [discussion on the meta Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/135907), with solid arguments for and against.